# How to use routes from submodule in NextJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, symlink

I have this project where I would like to use the routes/pages of a dashboard as defined in a git submodule. So, somehow I need to 'merge' the `pages` (or `app` folder in Nextjs13) folder with the one in the submodule.
Symlinks don't seem to be respected by NextJS, as it will simply throw a 404 page.
Are there any other methods that I am not aware of?

**So in short: How to expose routes from a submodule to NextJS?**

So the desired file structure is:

```
- pages (the nextjs file-based routes)
  - index.tsx
  - about.tsx
  - dashboard (should come from submodules/dashboard/pages)
    - index.tsx
    - stats.tsx
    - login.tsx
- public
- submodules
  - dashboard
    - pages
      - index.tsx
      - stats.tsx
      - login.tsx
```

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? I would suggest using hard links